# Read XLSX file from Azure Blob Storage using Azure Powershell Function

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, inputbinding

I have a http triggered function in Azure. In that function, i have added Azure Blob storage binding for reading the data. Now I am struggling to read the excel file in the function using powershell. There are many examples out there in the internet, but in different programming languages. Can someone please help with powershell?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Open XML SDK (.net ) in Azure functions to read .xlsx files that are present in Blob storage.

The following article has the implementation of using Open xml sdk in Azure blob triggered functions.

**Read file content of Excel file on Azure Blob Storage:**
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1b4768e5-ff6b-4b28-8223-c7380353c0c1/read-file-content-of-excel-file-on-azure-blob-storage

**Using Open XML with Powershell:**
https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2302788-using-openxml-with-powershell